# Meteor Method.call issue in jquery-validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-validate

I have a form to change password. I need to validate the old password. But  jquery `addMethod` is always return `false` in `Meteor.call`. How to make it workable. Or is there any way?  My bellow code will be more details about my issue.

```
  $.validator.addMethod( 'checkPassword', ( oldpassword ) => {
    var digest = Package.sha.SHA256(oldpassword);
    Meteor.call('checkPassword', digest, function(err, result) {
     var res = result.error != null; // even if this is "true", error message is visible.
     return res;
    });
  });


  $( "#changepassword" ).validate({
        rules: {
          oldpassword: {
            required: true,
            checkPassword: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          oldpassword: {
            required: "Please enter your Old Password",
            checkPassword: "Password doesnt match!!!" //this message is visible all the time.
          }    }
      });
```

Here is my method call

```
Meteor.methods({
  checkPassword: function(digest){
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
       if (this.userId) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        var password = {digest: digest, algorithm: 'sha-256'};
        var result = Accounts._checkPassword(user, password);
        return result;
    }
  }
}
});
```

[here](https://atmospherejs.com/themeteorchef/jquery-validation) the meteor package

Comment: Are you sure the jquery validator can handle asynchronous method calls? I had a glance through the docs and didn't immediately see any examples or mention of async anywhere.